# unexpected result from printf("%d",*p++);

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
   int a[3] = {10,20,30};
   int *p;
   p = a;
   printf("%d %d %d\n", a[0], a[1], a[2]);
   printf("%d %d %d\n", p[0], p[1], p[2]);
   printf("%d %d %d\n", *p, *(p+1), *(p+2));
   printf("%d %d %d\n", *p++, *p++, *p++);
}
```

> expected result
> 10 20 30
> 10 20 30
> 10 20 30
> **10 20 30**

> result
> 10 20 30
> 10 20 30
> 10 20 30
> **30 20 10**

Comment: Probably because the parser and generator processes parameters right to left.

Comment: @dbush the dupe is incorrect. Sequence points are defined here, order of evaluation of parameters is not

Comment: @0___________: What sequence points do you think there are in `printf("%d %d %d\n", *p++, *p++, *p++);`?

Comment: @0___________ The dup specifically addresses this case.

Comment: @박고은 No one can say how `printf("%d %d %d\n", *p++, *p++, *p++)` is evaluated.  You may have thought it would be evaluated left-to-right, but no: it might be evaluated in any order, and in fact it's undefined.